# Updating User Emails Python API

Tags: python, rest, api, python-requests

I am using Jitbit help desk API. I would need to update the email address for 200 user's. I am not sure how to pass the values to the parameters they have on their website. I have included documentation below. Basically I have a space delimited text file with user IDs and updated user emails. I attempted to take the values from the file and insert them into a dictionary with key value pairs, but realized I have no parameters to pass these to. Any assistance will be much appreciated! This is what I have so far, very stuck.

```
import requests


d = {}  
with open("file.txt") as f:  
    for line in f:  
        (key, val) = line.split()  
        d[int(key)] = val  

response = requests.post('https://companyname.jitbit.com/api/UpdateUser',auth=('username','password'), data=d)  

print(response)
```

**API Documentation:**
https://www.jitbit.com/helpdesk/helpdesk-api/#users-updateuser-post
UPDATEUSER (POST)- In the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API endpoint only updates one user at a time. Try this:

```py
import requests

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        user_id, email = line.split()
        response = requests.post(
            'https://companyname.jitbit.com/api/UpdateUser',
            auth=('username', 'password'),
            data=dict(
                userId=user_id,
                email=email,
            ),
        )
        print(response)
```

Comment: When I am testing this and delete all requests related syntax and simply print the data. I see that it is putting the ID field as a string as well. In the API the user ID accepted is a Int. How could I make the value for the userID an int type?  
  
{'userID': '8731555', 'email': 'blue@industries.com'}
{'userID': '8728555', 'email': 'joe@industries.com'}
{'userID': '8731222', 'email': 'ground@industries.com'}
{'userID': '8732222', 'email': 'day@industries.com'}